# How to properly disconnect and release resources for a boost::beast websocket stream?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-beast

I have a class `WsClient` which wraps a `boost::beast::websocket::stream`

```
class WsClient
{
    using TcpStream = boost::beast::tcp_stream;
    using SslStream = boost::beast::ssl_stream<TcpStream>;
    using WsStream = boost::beast::websocket::stream<SslStream>;

    ...

    WsStream _stream;
};
```

This class is used in a single threaded manner (that is, all interactions with the websocket client is done in the same thread context that the `asio::io_context` is running in.

I would like to safely and completely shut the websocket client down, disable/disconnect all asynchronous operations, and free up the resources associated with it.

In the [reference documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__websocket__stream.html) for `boost::beast::websocket::stream` I find there is a function [`async_close`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__websocket__stream/async_close.html).

The documentation says that `async_close` should be followed by a read until an error `error::closed` is returned, and at this point, the connection is successfully closed.

As such, I've written the following which intiates the `async_close`, and in the completion handler it repeatedly initiates an `async_read` until I get back `error::closed`.

```
void WsClient::close()
{
    auto self = shared_from_this();

    _stream.async_close(ws::close_code::normal,
                        [self](boost::system::error_code ec)
                        {
                            self->drainSocket({}, 0);
                        });
}

void WsClient::drainSocket(boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t)
{
     if (ec != boost::beast::websocket::error::closed)
          _stream.async_read(_read_buf, std::bind_front(&WsClient::drainSocket, shared_from_this()));

     // else 
     //     we're done, callback ends, shared_ptr goes out of scope, resources deleted
}
```

It all seems rather contrived, and I am struggling to believe this is the best way to close a websocket connection, discard any and all subsequent data, and free the resources.

In an ideal world I'd be able to just initiate the close, and then deregister the stream object from the `io_context` and then delete it.

All the extra callbacks and reading the socket just to discard the data seems overkill.

- Is this the right way to close down a beast websocket?
- If I don't care about any subsequent data, and I don't even care if I do an ungraceful shutdown and just sever the connection no matter what, is there a "better" way to just kill the connection and delete the stream without causing dangling references inside beast/asio?

Comment: Single threaded essentially means that you are running everything synchronously, which is the case with most client side applications. If you are running synchronously, then you need not explicitly `close` anything, nor do you need smart pointers; because there are no completion handlers. If you are running asynchronous(server side), then you'd better make sure the class outlives any async operations referencing it; this is done by passing a copy of the `shared_ptr` to object as a by value capture in completion lambda. Close and reopen is not a common practice in C++.

Comment: Well I'm single threaded but using an event loop, and doing async calls so that I don't block the event loop while waiting for the call to complete. When I want to close the socket if I free the resources without doing the above dance I can get segfaults because the io_context handler tries to access memory which I've freed

Comment: @Red.Wave single threaded does not mean synchronous. At all. See e.g. https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can ascribe a lot of it down to "WebSocket specs are a bit convoluted". There are many (server) implementations that don't quite stick to the letter. Even the implementations that do try to stick to the letter often get it tragically wrong (e.g. by inadvertently sending data past the close).

In the general case playing fast and loose may have security implications. I feel that Beast intends to be a "straight up", "low-level" if you will, websocket implementation. If you want to have higher level abstractions, you're going to build on top of it. As such you would only have 1 place in your application or library where this extra async read happens.

The recommendations as posted make sense as per-spec good-practice. For completeness, note that at least [latest version has the following](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__websocket__stream/async_close.html):

> Instead, the program should continue reading message data ***until an error occurs***. A read returning `error::closed` indicates a successful connection closure

So your handler is overly specific with regards to the error - which could create problems. I'd suggest the much simpler:

```
 if (!ec.failed())
```